# How to implement Facebook login in Struts 2?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, struts2

i am developing an application in  Struts2, in which i want to implement authentication  using Facebook.
I have registered my app in FaceBook and i got AppId and App Secret. using this i am doing facebook login  `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=241562345966486&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/myApp//jsps/loginFacebookUser.action&scope=email,user_birthday&state=1"><b>Facebook Connect</b></a>`

But not able to get `access_taken`.

Comment: As this question stands no one is going to be able to help you. You must have at least tried to do it. If you don't have any idea you should go back to basics and learn Struts2 and the Facebook API/Security in depth.

Comment: @Alex thank you for your advise,i already tried this, but that was my fault i didn't mention all the thing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post any code, it's hard to determine what exactly the problem is.

I'm not particularly familiar with FB's login API; however, the underlying mechanism is web services i.e. you send data to it, and it returns data back to you.

So, first, ensure that you are receiving a response back (usually a session ID or something similar) from FB.

If you received it, you have to save the data in a session object, and then explicitly give the user permission into your system. FB won't do that for you; you have to do that on your system.

Hope that makes sense. Check out the information on FB's API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login